# Suma de relacionados en una ubicacion MATRIZ en C

Tags: c

he podido resolver este problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que busco, reducir la cantidad de ifs que utilizo, pero no se me ocurre otra manera, o pensarlo de otra forma.

```c
 #include<stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int a[30][30];
    int cF;
    int cC;
}TArreglo;

void cargaDatos(TArreglo *k);
void sumaVecinos(TArreglo k);

int main(){

    TArreglo matriz;

    cargaDatos(&matriz);
    sumaVecinos(matriz);

    return 0;
}

void cargaDatos(TArreglo *k){

    int i;
    int j;

    do{
        printf("Recuerde que la cantidad de filas debe ser mayor a 2 y menor que 31\n");
        printf("Cargue la cantidad de FILAS de su matriz: \n");
        scanf("%d",&k->cF);
    } while (k->cF <= 1 || k->cF > 30);

    do{
        printf("Recuerde que la cantidad de columnas debe ser mayor a 2 y menor que 31\n");
        printf("Cargue la cantidad de COLUMNAS de su matriz: \n");
        scanf("%d",&k->cC);
    } while (k->cC <= 1 || k->cC > 30);

    for(i = 0; i < k->cF; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < k->cC; j++){
            printf("Seleccionar valor de fila %d y columna %d\n", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d",&k->a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void sumaVecinos(TArreglo k){

    int i;
    int j;
    int suma;

    for(i = 0; i < k.cF; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < k.cC; j++){
        
// SUMAS DISTINTAS PARA LOS VALORES LIMITE DE LA MATRIZ.

    // FILA 1, COLUMNA 1.
            if(i == 0 && j == 0){
                suma = k.a[i+1][j] + k.a[i][j+1];   
            }

    // FILA FINAL, COLUMNA 1.
            if(i == k.cF - o1 && j == 0){
                suma = k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i][j+1];
            }

    // FILA 1 COLUMNA FINAL.
            if(i == 0 && j == k.cC - 1){
                suma = k.a[i+1][j] + k.a[i][j-1];
            }
            
    // FILA FINAL, COLUMNA FINAL.
            if(i == k.cF - 1 && j == k.cC - 1){
                suma = k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i][j-1];
            }

    // LIMITES SUPERIORES.
            if(i == 0 && (j > 0 && j < k.cC - 1)){
                suma = k.a[i+1][j] + k.a[i][j+1] + k.a[i][j-1];
            }

    // LIMITES INFERIORES
            if(i == k.cF - 1 && (j > 0 && j < k.cC - 1)){
                suma = k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i][j+1] + k.a[i][j-1]; 
            }
            
    // LIMITES IZQUIERDOS.
            if((i > 0 && i < k.cF - 1) && j == 0){
                suma = k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i+1][j] + k.a[i][j+1];
            }

    // LIMITES DERECHOS.
            if((i > 0 && i < k.cF - 1) && j == k.cC - 1){
                suma = k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i][j-1] + k.a[i][j+1];         
            }

    // VALORES INTERNOS.
            if((i > 0 && i < k.cF - 1) && (j > 0 && j < k.cC - 1)){
                suma = k.a[i+1][j] + k.a[i-1][j] + k.a[i][j+1] + k.a[i][j-1];
            }

// DEVOLUCION.
            if(k.a[i][j] == suma){
                printf("En la fila %d y columna %d; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor %d\n", i+1, j+1, suma);
            }

// SUMA = 0 PARA VOLVER A REALIZAR EL BUCLE CON OTROS VALORES.
            suma = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Si tienen alguna sugerencia, (Sigo escribiendo porque me pide más detalles el post)
Lo que busco es poder resolverlo sin la necesidad de usar tantos condicionales, habia pensado inicializar en 1 hasta cantidadeColumnas-1 (recorrer internamente) pero no sé...

Completo detalles..

Completo detalles..

Completo detalles..

Completo detalles..
Completo detalles..
Completo detalles..
Completo detalles..
Completo detalles..

Comment: La variable `o1` no está declarada. Corrige el código para poder trabajar con él

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes tomar en cuenta es lo siguiente:

**1.** Para obtener el límite superior de una determinada posición, se debe restar un `- 1` al índice `i` (esta variable guarda el índice de la fila).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
matriz[i - 1][j]
```

**2.** Para obtener el límite inferior de una determinada posición, se debe sumar un `+ 1` al índice `i`.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
matriz[i + 1][j]
```

**3.** Para obtener el vecino izquierdo de una determinada posición, se debe restar `- 1` al índice `j` (esta variable guarda el índice de la columna).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
matriz[i][j - 1]
```

**4.** Para obtener el vecino derecho de una determinada posición, se debe sumar `+ 1` al índice `j`.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
matriz[i][j + 1]
```

Sin embargo, hay que evitar un posible desbordamiento de búfer, eso se lo restringe con una condición.

La implementación quedaría así:

```c
int sumaVecinos(int array[][M], int fil, int col)
{
    int suma = 0;
    suma += (fil + 1 != N)  ? array[fil + 1][col] : 0; //Sumar limite inferior.
    suma += (fil - 1 != -1) ? array[fil - 1][col] : 0; //Sumar limite superior.
    suma += (col - 1 != -1) ? array[fil][col - 1] : 0; //Sumar vecino izquierdo.
    suma += (col + 1 != M)  ? array[fil][col + 1] : 0; //Sumar vecino derecho.
    return suma;
}
```

Cada vez que intenemos desbordar el array, el [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) devolverá un `0` y listo, de esta manera nos ahorramos `9` ifs.

**Uso:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define  N 4 
#define  M 5

int sumaVecinos(int array[][M], int fil, int col)
{
    int suma = 0;
    suma += (fil + 1 != N)  ? array[fil + 1][col] : 0; //Sumar limite inferior.
    suma += (fil - 1 != -1) ? array[fil - 1][col] : 0; //Sumar limite superior.
    suma += (col - 1 != -1) ? array[fil][col - 1] : 0; //Sumar vecino izquierdo.
    suma += (col + 1 != M)  ? array[fil][col + 1] : 0; //Sumar vecino derecho.
    return suma;
}


int main(void)
{
    int suma;
    int array[N][M] = 
    {
        {3, 1, 8, 0, 0},
        {1, 4, 1, 0, 3},
        {0, 1, 0, 1, 6},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 2}
    };      
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
        
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            suma = sumaVecinos(array, i, j);
            if(suma == array[i][j])
                printf("(%d ; %d); = %d\n", i, j, suma);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

El código de ejemplo produce el siguiente resultado:

[image: resultado]

Puedes ver el código funcionando en este enlace: https://onlinegdb.com/SyJeLN0UD

Answer (score 0):

Dividir para reinar: primero hacemos una función que retorna el valor de una celda (fila, columna), incluso si los indices están fuera de rango, en cuyo caso se devuelve cero (no altera el valor de la suma).

```
int getValue(TArreglo k, int fila, int col) {
    
    if (fila < 0 || fila >= k.cF)
        return 0;
    
    if (col < 0 || col >= k.cC)
        return 0;
    
    return k.a[fila][col];  
}
```

Con eso se nos simplifica la vida, ya que podemos calcular la suma directamente, asi:

```
void sumaVecinos(TArreglo k){

    int fila;
    int col;
    int suma;

    for(fila = 0; fila < k.cF; fila++){
        for(col = 0; col < k.cC; col++){
            suma = getValue(k, fila-1, col) + getValue(k, fila+1, col) +
                   getValue(k, fila, col-1) + getValue(k, fila, col+1);
        
            if (k.a[fila][col] == suma){
                printf("En la fila %d y columna %d; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor %d\n", fila+1, col+1, suma);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que produce:

```
En la fila 2 y columna 2; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor 4
En la fila 3 y columna 5; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor 6
En la fila 4 y columna 1; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor 0
En la fila 4 y columna 3; la suma de sus vecinos es igual al valor 0
```

Nota:

Hay dos celdas más que las ejemplificadas en el enunciado, pero este resultado es correcto, pues la suma de sus vecinos existente es cero, igual que el contenido de la celda.